# Is there a way to acknowledge specific message in Pulsar?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Is there a way to acknowledge a particular message in a topic on behalf of a specific subscriber?

I couldn't find anything related to this in the api, both the admin and client api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Consumer.acknowledge(msg)` method is acknowledging the consumption of 1 specific message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you're trying to do this on an administrative basis, rather than via the typical consumer acknowledgment behavior of a subscriber using the Pulsar client. If your consumer is unable to process the message, for example, and you want to remove it from the backlog, you can skip the message.

```
pulsar-admin topics skip \
  --count 1 --subscription my-subscription \
  persistent://my-tenant/my-namespace/my-topic
```

Keep in mind that if you are using retention, skipping the message bypasses the mechanism that retains the message, so unless the message was already acknowledged and is stuck due to a bug, skipping will consequently schedule the message for deletion.

Comment: My requirement is to find specific message and acknowledge it. So I used Reader to find the message & ack it.